# Border-radius property not working in outlook

Tags: css, outlook-2016

I have a button in my email, which when viewed through outlook has some problems with border radius. It is not considering the styles which I give for border-radius and padding. But the same is supported in the browser and working as expected. Is there any hack to make these styles working in outlook?

```
 <td style="border-radius: 2px;" bgcolor="#0c6cd7">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

border-radius property is not supported by outlook, as it uses MS-word template. we need to code for outlook too. Please find the below piece of code which will work for both outlook and browser or other email clients.

```
<td>
  <div>
    <!--[if mso]>
      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://example.com" style="height:36px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" arcsize="5%" strokecolor="#EB7035" fillcolor="#EB7035">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;">I am a button &rarr;</center>
      </v:roundrect>
    <![endif]-->
    <a href="http://example.com" style="background-color:#EB7035;border:1px solid #EB7035;border-radius:3px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:44px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:150px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">I am a button &rarr;</a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Could you explain this approach please?

Comment: @AliAlizade Please use the above snippet to adjust your border radius. outlook uses a template where the border radius is not supported, hence we are writing it here.

Answer (score 4):

According to [**CanIEmail**](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-border-radius/) the `border-radius` property won't work in Outlook on Windows.

There could also be some issues with padding, so I would suggest working strongly with tables and filling the `padding` space with empty table rows/columns.

Comment: What u told is exactly correct!. I am using tables as u said. but, in that for the border radius property even padding doesn't help out. So I have researched and found something which helped to solve my issue. please find my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I just got the same issue. after some research, I found a website. that is helping to generate a rounded button(and so more) for outlook.

Here is the website: https://buttons.cm/

I know the question is very old, but hopefully, this will help others to resolve the problem connected with the buttons on outlook :)

Answer (score -3):

Looks like your button is inside the td tag apply your styles to the button element instead of td

`<td bgcolor="#0c6cd7"> <button style="border-radius: 2px;"`

Comment: This doesn't work, see other answers. Outlook ignores the `border-radius` style.

Answer (score -5):

It's not related to the Outlook. It's related to the element that you are using . Please try this:

```html
<table>
<tr><td ><p style="border-radius: 2px; background:#0c6cd7">test</p></td></tr>
</table>
```

Or you can use separate CSS, but it might be effect other styles:

```css
table tr td {
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  background:#0c6cd7;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td >test</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Outlook's use of Word templates limits functionality of html-based emails. It is really a poor choice, probably left over from their attempt to take over HTML.